# Reorder the selected items in AngularJS ui-select multiple

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-select

Is it possible to automatically reorder the selected items in AngularJS ui-select of type multiple?

Here is a code sample, there are more on [ui-select github](http://angular-ui.github.io/ui-select/demo-multiple-selection.html)

```
<ui-select multiple ng-model="ctrl.multipleDemo.colors" theme="bootstrap" ng-disabled="ctrl.disabled" close-on-select="false" style="width: 300px;" title="Choose a color">
<ui-select-match placeholder="Select colors...">{{$item}}</ui-select-match>
<ui-select-choices repeat="color in ctrl.availableColors | filter:$select.search">
  {{color}}
</ui-select-choices>
```

Here is a screen-shot of its behavior :

[image]

What I would like is the selected items to be reorder : even if when I selected the items I selected first Yellow, then Green, then Blue, I would like it to be Blue, Green, Yellow.

I have seen an attribute called sortable="true" but it doesn't seem to do what I expect.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try to add `on-select="$select.selected.sort()"`:

```
<ui-select multiple 
         ng-model="ctrl.multipleDemo.colors" 
         on-select="$select.selected.sort()"
         theme="bootstrap" 
         ng-disabled="ctrl.disabled" 
         close-on-select="false" 
         style="width: 300px;" 
         title="Choose a color">
  <ui-select-match placeholder="Select colors...">{{$item}}</ui-select-match>
  <ui-select-choices repeat="color in ctrl.availableColors | filter:$select.search">
    {{color}}
  </ui-select-choices>
</ui-select>
```

updated plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/Bms3pDdn6XnS2b7gsyQ5?p=preview

Comment: thanx for your update, it does work if the list of the ui-select is a list of string : vm.availableColors = ['Red','Green','Blue','Yellow','Magenta','Maroon','Umbra','Turquoise']; but how can I make it work with objects? For instance if vm.availableColors = [{id: 1, name : 'Blue'}, {id: 2, name : 'Magenta'}, {id: 3, name : 'Yellow'}] ?

Comment: for your example array of object you can use `$select.selected.sort((a, b) => a.name.localeCompare(b.name))`.  Here we are using our custom sort function which compares strings

Comment: Thank you for your update. I am sorry, I am quite new with Javascript/Angular JS, can you please update the plunker with the ui-select "Array of objects (sorting enabled)" to see how it works. I have tried to add the code you gave 

`<h3>Array of objects (sorting enabled)</h3>
  <ui-select multiple on-select="$select.selected.sort((a, b) = a.name.localeCompare(b.name))" ng-model="ctrl.multipleDemo.selectedPeople" ...>`

But it gives an error in the console : 

`Token ',' is unexpected, expecting [)] at column 25 of the expression [$select.selected.sort((a, b) = a.name.localeCompare....`

Comment: sorry, I did not mentioned, that you cannot add this function as angular expression within HTML, so, in HTML I added a function which is declared in controller, I updated my plunker

Comment: You rock, thanx a lot! If I could I would give +10 for your answer.